# How to close image connection after inserting to picturebox?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I open a image into picturebox and copy it to my clipboard, i want to dispose that image so that if i was to open it separately from my document, i can still open it or edit the file name without it complaining i have it open with my application. Here's my open image:

```
For Each fi As FileInfo In New DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles(file1 & "*.jpg")
    Dim xx As Image
    Using st As Stream = File.OpenRead(path & fi.ToString)
        xx = Image.FromStream(st)

        Clipboard.Clear()
        Clipboard.SetImage(xx)

        Dim realpic As New PictureBox()
        realpic.Image = Clipboard.GetImage
        'realpic.Tag = fi.fullname
        realpic.Height = 113
        realpic.Width = 145
        realpic.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        realpic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom

        AddHandler realpic.MouseClick, AddressOf pictureBox_MouseClick
        picturePreview.Controls.Add(realpic)
    End Using   
Next
```

While the application shows the image in my picturebox, if i try to change the name of the file directly from the document it is located, i will get prompt that my application has the image opened. I need to open image and dispose of it so that if i want to do whatever else with the image directly i can? Help?

Comment: You could use an image object - a variable - in place of a temp picturebox and the user's clipboard.  If you also want to fiddle with the file, clone/copy the image and dispose of the original

Comment: @Plutonix check update, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim pbx As New PictureBox()
    Dim rn As New Random
    Dim pth As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "\pic" & rn.Next(0, 1000000) & fi.SafeFileName.Substring(fi.SafeFileName.Length - 4, 4)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(fi.FileName, pth)
    pbx.Image = Image.FromFile(pth)
    Clipboard.Clear()
    Clipboard.SetImage(pbx.Image)
    pbx.Image = Nothing
    pbx.Dispose()
```